# Asymptotic running time function's domain

Tags: algorithms, asymptotics

I am reading CLRS and have uncertainty in asymptotic running time of algorithms. In CLRS, it is said,

> The notations we use to describe the asymptotic running time of an algorithm are defined in terms of functions whose domains are the set of natural numbers $N = \{0,1,2,...\}.$ such notations are convenient for describing the worst-case runtime function $T(n)$ which usually is defined only on integer input sizes. We sometimes find it convenient, however, to abuse asymptotic notation in a variety of ways for example we might extend the notation to the domain of real numbers, or alternatively restrict it to subset of the natural numbers

My first question is what is asymptotic running time of an algorithm. Some simply says that it refers to the order of growth of the function, while other describes it using limits. Then, why we take the domain as the natural number and in what cases abuse it, meaning to take the domain as reals. what it gives us to take reals as the function's domain?
I appreciate your answers.

Comment: We usually measure the (worst case) running time as a function of the input length, which is an integer.

Comment: I'm not sure what CLRS refer to when they allow the function to take fractional inputs. Perhaps they mean recurrence relations such as $T(n) = 2T(n/2) + n$, in which we allow $n$ to be odd (or worse).